# How to compare a data value against values in an list

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to search through a list of values, which could be any type (int, string, bool, and so-on), and I can't find a way to compare a given value against values in the list.

My code so far:

---

```
public void Countin(T data)
{
    int numbersOf = 0;
    Node pTmp = first;
    while (pTmp != null)
    {
         if (pTmp.Equals(data))
         {
             numbersOf++
             pTmp = pTmp.Next;
         }
         else
         {
              pTmp = pTmp.Next;
         }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {numbersOf} {data} in the list.");
}
```

---

With a list of
"I" "am" "getting" "really" "really" "tired" "of" "this",

I keep getting the output of "There are 0 really in the list". And when I swap the numbersOf++ from  to the 'else', I get "There are 8 really in the list."

The rest of the code works fine, it's just that "pTmp.Equals(data)" isn't doing what I think it should be doing, but I can't just use pTmp == data, due to 'data' being an element in a list.

Any help?

Every part of the above code works fine EXCEPT FOR COMPARING pTmp TO data! Nothing else needs help! I just need a way to compare the data variable to the values in the list.

FINAL EDIT:

All I had to do was change the boolean to if (Equals(pTmp.Data),data), and it worked. All I needed as an answer was 'Equals(x,y) will do what you want'. Thanks guys.

Comment: why are you using generics? does it really needed? It doesn't seem like

Comment: I'm using generics because the list is user-generated and I don't know what values will be there.

Comment: the values are is of type string. what can it be other than string?

Comment: I think you are missing something, this code does not compile `Node pTmp = first;`. Where is the variable `first` declared ?

Comment: `Node` should contain the `Value` or `Data` property. So you should compare `pTmp.Value.Equals(data)`

Comment: The comparison will only be successful if the values being compared have overridden [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1) methods.

Comment: Node does not contain the Value or Data property, and I'm blanking on how to add it.

Comment: Then how did you put the values in the list? / Show us more code.

Comment: Don't write the answer in the question. Do it as it should, with a separate answer.